# How to use a custom class method in a Pyomo constraint?

Tags: python, pyomo, scipy-optimize

I am working on an optimization problem where I need to determine which items need to be discarded to satisfy local constraints, with some additional complexities.

To start off, I have a dictionary (`ITEM_DICT`) with all items that can be discarded with the key being the item id. Each value in the dictionary is an instance of a class I created with a method (`checkItemCondition`) for checking whether the conditions for the item are satisfied (this is because the condition is a function of this item and select other items). Only some items are allowed to be discarded (`choice_set`, which is an array of `item_id`). I've currently set the code up as follows:

The variable is binary and indicates whether the item is discarded or not.

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo
from pyomo.environ import value

model = pyo.ConcreteModel()
S = set(choice_set) 
model.S = pyo.Set(initialize = S)
model.discard_proposal = pyo.Var(model.S, domain = pyo.Binary) # binary decision, 1 = discard; 0 = keep
```

Because I want to satisfy all constraints for all items after implementing the discard proposal, I define the following constraint:

```
def post_discard_constraint(model):
    global ITEM_DICT
    # Implement discard proposal as the conditions should be checked post-discard.
    for item_id in model.S:
        if value(model.discard_proposal[item_id] > 0):  # 1 = discard
            ITEM_DICT[item_id].setStatus(True) # set to discard
        else:
            ITEM_DICT[item_id].setStatus(False) # 0 = Keep; set to keep
    
    # Check post-discard item conditions
    for item_id in model.S:
        if not ITEM_DICT[item_id].checkItemCondition(): # if any item does not have its conditions satisfied, return that the constraint is not satisfied
            return pyo.Constraint.Infeasible
    return pyo.Constraint.Feasible

model.post_discard_constraint = pyo.Constraint(rule = post_discard_constraint)
```

The issue is that the constraint does not appear to initialize properly. It says that it is always infeasible and never returns a solution (even though I know there is a solution from a combinatorial exercise).

So my question is two-fold: is there a way to fix this (preserving the `checkItemCondition` method, since the condition is not linear and is relational) and, if not, how should I go about solving it?

Thanks!

Comment: The problem is not with using a custom class of objects.  The problem here is that you are attempting to make a conditional statement inside of the constraint based on the value of a model variable.  This is illegal/not possible.  The values of the variables are NOT KNOWN when the constraint is built.  That is the solver's job.  You will need to reformulate your problem and capture this logic in a different construct

Comment: Thanks @AirSquid , To make sure I understand, just getting rid of the if/then statement wouldn't fix it either because the discard proposal is unknown in the constraint, so I wouldn't be able to change `ITEM_DICT` based on a proposed value? Do you have any sources/recommendations for what to read or how to rewrite the problem? Where the individual constraints are a function of other item's status.

Comment: You will need to express the constraint(s) on `discard_proposal` in terms of basic linear mathematical operations.  It isn't clear what those rules are from context.  For instance if you can only discard 5 things max, then you'd have some sum(discards) <= 5, etc.